# Django Admin. Disable `list_editable` fields for editing after date?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

> Django 2.0.3, Python 3.6.1

I have standard Django admin panel. For one of my model I create `list_editable` with some fields (`provider` and `provider_price` on screenshot). Question is: *How to disable those `list_editable` fields for edit after some date?*

For example, if now is `March 11, 2018` and older, fields `provider` and `provider_price` are disabled and doesn't edit in list view (only in single record change view).

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`ModelAdmin.get_changelist_form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_changelist_form). Something like this:

```
class TouristVisaInvitationListForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if should_be_disabled(self.instance.date): # whatever condition you want
            self.fields['provider'].disabled = True
            self.fields['provider_price'].disabled = True

class TouristVisaInvitationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    .
    .
    .
    def get_changelist_form(self, request, **kwargs):
        return TouristVisaInvitationListForm
```

Comment: It works only if I delete `self` from `super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)`. Can you help me to understand why?

Comment: Not much to understand, it was my mistake :) I corrected the answer, but I suppose you figured it out in the mean time.